# Suppose a function maps a region conformally show that the area...

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose a function $w=f(z) \in H(\Omega)$ maps a region $\Omega$ conformally onto a region $\Omega'$: show that the area of $\Omega'$ is given by $$\iint_\Omega |f'(z)|^2 \, dx \, dy$$

I am trying to find the connection between mapping conformally and the conclusion but I cannot seem to find the correlation.

Comment: The important part here is that the map is bijective.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. For instance, $w = e^z$ maps the strip $\Omega = 0 \le y \le 4\pi, 0 \le x \le 1$ onto an annulus of inner radius 1 and outer radius $e$. whose area is therefore $\pi(e^2 - 1)$, but the integral above will give twice this value. You really need to say that it maps conformally and 1-1 onto $\Omega'$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I'm pretty sure whoever posed the exercise belongs to the school of "conformal = biholomorphic", not "conformal = locally biholomorphic".

Comment: Ah... I see. A complex analyst rather than, say, a differential geometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
z & = x+iy \\[8pt]
f(z) & = u+iv \\[8pt]
& x,y,u,v \in\mathbb R \\[8pt]
df & = f'(z_0)\,dz \\[8pt]
du + i\,dv  & = df = f'(z_0)\,dz = (a+ib)\,dz \\[8pt]
& = (a+ib)(dx + i\,dy) \\[8pt]
& =  (a\,dx-b\,dy) + i(a\,dy + b\,dx)
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\begin{bmatrix} du \\ dv \end{bmatrix}
= \left[ \begin{array}{rr} a & -b \\ b & a \end{array} \right]
\begin{bmatrix} dx \\ dy \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Multiplying by a matrix has the effect of multiplying areas in the domain by the absolute value of the determinant to get the corresponding areas in the codomain.  The determinant is
$$
a^2 + b^2 = |f'(z_0)|^2.
$$
Therefore the element of area is $|f'(z_0)|^2\,dx\,dy$.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat of John Hughes, the property is simply a particular case of the multivariable change of variable theorem. Namely, if $f=u+iv$:
$$Jf(z) = \left|\matrix{u_x&u_y\cr v_x&v_y}\right|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try a change of variable.

You know that the area of $\Omega'$ is given by $$
\iint_{\Omega'}\,dxdy
$$
and that $\Omega'=f(\Omega)$ (I am assuming that when you say "conformally", you mean that $f$ is injective and holomorphic, as you need injectivity for the formula to hold, as the comments above show).

Comment: Conformal maps simply preserve angles (at least by some definitions); as the example in my comment above shows, that doesn't imply injectivity.

Comment: Sorry, I thought local injectivity was enough, but that's not true. $f$ must be biholomorphic.

Comment: Only if you're willing to say that area can be "double counted"...

Comment: You are totally correct. Probably I was being more a complex analyst than a differential geometer. Thank you.