# Holomorphic function that locally keeps the area invariant

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the complex plane and if $f$ locally keeps the area invariant, that is for each point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and any neighbourhood of $z_0$, the area of $f(\Omega)$ is equal to the area of $\Omega$. What will the function $f$ be?

My attempt: I believe the $f$ has to be of the form $f(z) = \pm z + a$ and $f(z) = \pm i z + a$ where $a \in \mathbb{C}$, consisting only of only translations. However, I am not sure how to proceed with this question. I considering the image of the unit disk under $f$ however, I am not sure if the image of $f(D)$ is also a disk of radius one, let alone a simply connected domain. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What about $f(z)=iz$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you, I have made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D \subset \Bbb C$ be a domain (open and connected) and $f: D \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic and locally area preserving, i.e. every $z_0 \in D$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $A(f(\Omega)) = A(\Omega)$ for all neighborhoods $\Omega \subset U$ of $z_0$.

First show that $f'$ has no zeros in $D$ ($f'(z_0) = 0$ would imply that $f$ is locally a contraction).

So $f$ is locally injective and every $z_0 \in D$ has a neighborhood $U'$ in which $f$ is injective and area-preserving. The area $A(f(\Omega))$ for $\Omega \subset U'$ is then given by the formula
$$A(f(\Omega)) = \iint_\Omega |f'(z)|^2 \, dx \, dy \, ,$$
see for example [Suppose a function maps a region conformally show that the area...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1660545/42969).

It follows that $|f'(z_0)| = 1$: If $|f'(z_0)| < 1$ then $|f'(z)| < 1$ in some neighborhood $\Omega \subset U' $ of $z_0$ and $A(f(\Omega)) < A(\Omega)$. Similarly we get a contradiction if $|f'(z_0)| > 1$.

It follows that $|f'(z)|=1$ for all $z \in D$, and that implies that  $f'$ is constant in $D$ (e.g. by the open mapping theorem).

This shows that $f$ is necessarily of the form $f(z) = a + bz$ with constants $a, b \in \Bbb C$ and $|b|  = 1$.